# What are Java command line options to set to allow JVM to be remotely debugged?

Tags: java, debugging

I know there's some `JAVA_OPTS` to set to remotely debug a Java program.

What are they and what do they mean ?

Answer (score 383, accepted):

I have [this article](http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t53459.html) bookmarked on setting this up for Java 5 and below.

Basically [run it with](http://download.oracle.com/otn_hosted_doc/jdeveloper/904preview/jdk14doc/docs/tooldocs/windows/jdb.html):

```
-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=1044
```

For [Java 5 and above](http://javahowto.blogspot.ru/2010/09/java-agentlibjdwp-for-attaching.html), run it with:

```
-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=1044
```

If you want Java to **wait for you to connect** before executing the application, replace `suspend=n` with `suspend=y`.

Comment: Worth to mention is that you might want to configure your address like `*:1044` to enable remote debugging from any computer

Comment: HerrDerb is right.. Since Java 9 "address=1044" is not always listening on all interfaces. "address=*:1044" makes Java 9+ behave like Java 8...

Comment: Just a note: It is _**not required**_ to add the `address` parameter. If not provided the agent is selecting a random port number.

This might be useful if you start multiple nodes within the same java command line.

Comment: its also safer to use `address=localhost:<debug port>` vs just selecting the port

Answer (score 525):

Before Java 5.0, use `-Xdebug` and `-Xrunjdwp` arguments. These options will still work in later versions, but it will run in interpreted mode instead of JIT, which will be slower.

From Java 5.0, it is better to use the `-agentlib:jdwp` single option:

```
-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=1044
```

Options on `-Xrunjdwp` or `agentlib:jdwp` arguments are :

- `transport=dt_socket` : means the way used to connect to JVM (socket is a good choice, it can be used to debug a distant computer)
- `address=8000` : TCP/IP port exposed, to connect from the debugger (will only allow local connections, see Antony Shumskikh's answer for remote debugging)
- `suspend=y` : if 'y', tell the JVM to wait until debugger is attached to begin execution, otherwise (if 'n'), starts execution right away.

Comment: Your are exactly correct.. I tried with **-Xdebug** and **-Xrunjdwp** but It didn't work. when I tried with **-Xrunjdwp** or **agentlib:jdwp** It is working. ( on Java 7 )

Comment: This only worked for me when I put quotes around it, otherwise I got this error: ERROR: JDWP Non-server transport dt_socket server=y suspend=y address=8000 must have a connection address specified through the 'address=' option

Comment: Is `Xrunjdwp` deprecated (or removed?) why would we pick `agentlib:jdwp` over it?

Comment: I think you're wrong. Netbeans uses `-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp` when debugging Maven projects, and they run like they're JITed.

Answer (score 121):

Since Java 9.0 JDWP supports only local connections by default.
https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/9-all-relnotes.html#JDK-8041435

For remote debugging one should run program with `*:` in address:

```
-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=*:8000
```

Comment: Just making a note: the Oracle link says this will achieve the same old behavior, but it is not secure and not recommended.

Comment: Yeah, I wasted some days to find this answer for docker-compose, docker swarm debug remote with inteliji, just do exactly(with `*:`): address=*:5005

Comment: new non-dead link: https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/9-all-relnotes.html

Comment: In general I think it would be better (more secure, and generally better practice) to bind the port to localhost, and set up an ssh tunnel.

Answer (score 14):

For java 1.5 or greater:

```
java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005 <YourAppName>
```

For java 1.4:

```
java -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005 <YourAppName>
```

For java 1.3:

```
java -Xnoagent -Djava.compiler=NONE -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005 <YourAppName>
```

Here is output from a simple program:

```
java -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=1044 HelloWhirled
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 1044
Hello whirled
```

Answer (score 10):

#### java

```
java -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=8001,suspend=y -jar target/cxf-boot-simple-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

`address` specifies the port at which it will allow to debug

#### Maven

**Debug Spring Boot app with Maven:

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Drun.jvmArguments=**"-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=8001"
```

Answer (score 4):

### Command Line

```
-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=PORT_NUMBER
```

### Gradle

```
gradle bootrun --debug-jvm
```

### Maven

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Drun.jvmArguments="-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=PORT_NUMBER
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is the easiest solution for *maven* builds.

There are a lot of environment special configurations needed if you are using Maven. So, if you start your program from maven, just run the `mvnDebug` command instead of `mvn`, it will take care of starting your app with remote debugging configurated. Now you can just attach a debugger on port 8000.

It'll take care of all the environment problems for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=PORT_NUMBER
```

Here we just use a Socket Attaching Connector, which is enabled by default when the dt_socket transport is configured and the VM is running in the server debugging mode.

For more details u can refer to : https://stackify.com/java-remote-debugging/

Answer (score -1):

If you are using java 9 or higher, to remotely debug (which is also the case when you use docker at local) you have to provide `--debug *:($port)`. Because from java 9 `--debug ($port)` will only allow to debug ***at local, not remotely***.

So, you can provide command in docker-compose like
`command: -- /opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/standalone.sh --debug *:8787`