# Debugging Java Application Over Network

Tags: java, netbeans, networking, debugging

I have a core java app running on a computer on my network.  Can I attach a debugger (netbeans preferred) to this from another computer on the same network?

Please advise how to do this if it is possible, or point me to an article I've had a terrible time googling for it.  I don't see why it shouldn't be possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can.

Start your JVM with these arguments:

```
-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8001,server=y,suspend=n
```

The address number is the port number the JVM will listen on for a debugger to attach to. Set suspend to `y` if you want the JVM to wait until a debugger is attached before starting `main`.

Your debugger should have the option to connect to a remote JVM. It should be a simple matter of punching in the host and port number.

Comment: Thank you.  Yes the option is there and I found that,  the JVM args are what I was unaware of.

Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean a java app run from the CL by "core java"?  If so

[What are Java command line options to set to allow JVM to be remotely debugged?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138511/what-are-java-command-line-options-to-set-to-allow-jvm-to-be-remotely-debugged)

Once you tell the jvm to listen on a port, just point your netbeans debugging profile to the machine ip and port.  This should be very doable.