# java/Eclipse: starting a new JVM in Debug mode

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, jvm

Is it possible for my Java program to start a 2nd JVM (via [ProcessBuilder](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) for instance running `javaw.exe`) in Debug mode so it appears in Eclipse's debug window?

If so, how?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are Java command line options to set to allow JVM to be remotely debugged?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/138511/what-are-java-command-line-options-to-set-to-allow-jvm-to-be-remotely-debugged)

Comment: NOT A DUPLICATE, please read the whole question. This is an eclipse-specific question.

Answer (score 7):

A possible way to achieve what you (possibly) want: enable the second jvm for remote debugging. As far as I remember, you can tell the jvm to wait until the remote debugger is hooked to the session. Then, after that "child jvm" is spawned, start a remote debugging session in eclipse.

[This is the set of parameters for a classic VM](http://download.oracle.com/otn_hosted_doc/jdeveloper/904preview/jdk14doc/docs/tooldocs/windows/jdb.html):

```
java -Xdebug -Xnoagent -Djava.compiler=NONE 
     -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=5005 ...
```

(`suspend=y` tells the jvm to wait for the debugger, 5005 is the port in this example)

[Starting from JavaSE 1.5, these were replaced with a standardized parameter](http://javahowto.blogspot.ru/2010/09/java-agentlibjdwp-for-attaching.html):

```
java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=localhost:9009,server=y,suspend=y
```

Comment: more info at: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-eclipse-javadebug/index.html

Comment: Hmm. Well this *almost* works. The issue here is that the JVM will be launched sometime in the future, and I can't tell Eclipse to wait for later. It seems to expect that the JVM in question is available *now*.

Comment: @Jason - hmm, it was my understanding that you (1) start the parent application, (2) spawn the child jvm with suspend=y and then (3) start the remote debugging session in eclipse. That doesn't work?

Comment: That works only if I increase timeouts in my client / server apps to the point where I can tolerate the time needed to manually execute step (3) after manually executing step (1). If that's my only choice, I'll deal. I'd rather have step (3) occur automatically somehow.

Comment: @JasonS to execute step (3) automatically, Eclipse must be somehow listening for requests to start a debug session so that your app can send one.

Answer (score 3):

If you're working on an Eclipse plugin, you could use Eclipse's mechanism for starting a new application, using the DebugUITools, basically

```
org.eclipse.debug.core.DebugPlugin.launch(configuration, "debug");
```

I once used this to launch applications in debug mode, and it worked as expected, including full support on breakpoints set within eclipse, variable introspection etc. If this is what you're looking for, you should give it a try.

Comment: it's not an eclipse plugin, but this is useful information for future reference.