# how does jvm detects deadlock condition. What is the data structure and algorithm JVM implements to detect htread deadlock.

Tags: java, multithreading, jvm

I have been trying to find whether JVM has some way to find if some threads are in deadlock condition. I am unable to find any. Please let me know if any one of you gets any pointer on this.

Comment: check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/217113/deadlock-in-java

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [ThreadMXBean](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/management/ThreadMXBean.html) JMX bean.

```
ThreadMXBean threadMXBean = ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean();
ThreadInfo[] threadInfos = threadMXBean.dumpAllThreads(true, true);
long[] deadlockedThreads = threadMXBean.findDeadlockedThreads();
long[] monitorDeadlockedThreads = threadMXBean.findMonitorDeadlockedThreads();
```

Answer (score 0):

No, the JVM itself does not support deadlock detection.
There is a thread that deals with JVM and deadlocks, which is also marked as resolved: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8126711/1790635)