# JVM hangs after migrating to jdk1.8.0_74

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

I have a java application which used to run fine with java 7. After migrating to java 8 with the following confiugration it started to hang.

```
-Xms3g -Xmx3g -verbose:gc -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:G1ReservePercent=25 -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps
```

I have taken jstack dump and it shows that all threads are in **BLOCKED** state. I also have taken jmap dump which shows the following information.

Can someone help me in resolving this issue?

```
Attaching to process ID 2554, please wait...
Debugger attached successfully.
Server compiler detected.
JVM version is 25.74-b02

using thread-local object allocation.
Garbage-First (G1) GC with 18 thread(s)

Heap Configuration:
   MinHeapFreeRatio         = 40
   MaxHeapFreeRatio         = 70
   MaxHeapSize              = 3221225472 (3072.0MB)
   NewSize                  = 1363144 (1.2999954223632812MB)
   MaxNewSize               = 1932525568 (1843.0MB)
   OldSize                  = 5452592 (5.1999969482421875MB)
   NewRatio                 = 2
   SurvivorRatio            = 8
   MetaspaceSize            = 21807104 (20.796875MB)
   CompressedClassSpaceSize = 1073741824 (1024.0MB)
   MaxMetaspaceSize         = 17592186044415 MB
   G1HeapRegionSize         = 1048576 (1.0MB)

Heap Usage:
G1 Heap:
   regions  = 3072
   capacity = 3221225472 (3072.0MB)
   used     = 2112667712 (2014.7969360351562MB)
   free     = 1108557760 (1057.2030639648438MB)
   65.58583776156108% used
G1 Young Generation:
Eden Space:
   regions  = 1665
   capacity = 2024800256 (1931.0MB)
   used     = 1745879040 (1665.0MB)
   free     = 278921216 (266.0MB)
   86.22475401346452% used
Survivor Space:
   regions  = 5
   capacity = 5242880 (5.0MB)
   used     = 5242880 (5.0MB)
   free     = 0 (0.0MB)
   100.0% used
G1 Old Generation:
   regions  = 349
   capacity = 1191182336 (1136.0MB)
   used     = 361545792 (344.79693603515625MB)
   free     = 829636544 (791.2030639648438MB)
   30.351842960841218% used

18753 interned Strings occupying 1751224 bytes.
```

Comment: Your Eden space is quite busy and your Survivor Space is full, this is fairly normal - the Old Gen is quite empty. I would run again with either 1) print GC flags set, or 2) VisualVM attached.

Comment: Does it hang without any flags set?

Comment: Is it fully your app or does it run on a container? (Application server, OSGi container, ...)

Comment: Can you try running with the following flags as well and share output. -XX:+PrintGC -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -Xloggc:mygclogfilename.gc

Comment: @GabrielVince This is a standalone application.

Comment: It sounds like you have a thread safety bug.  You can write code which happens to work in one version on one machine, but change the OS, the machine or the JVM version and your bug can show up.  If all your threads are BLOCKED they are waiting for something.

Comment: @DROY I will set GC flag and shre the result.

Comment: Any chance you could post the tread dump - if @PeterLawrey is correct then it should be fairly simple to at least work out which monitor the threads are waiting for. You could also try [deadlock detection](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8126828/2071828) in VisualVM.

Comment: This issue is not reproduced yet. I will update once this issue is reproduced.

Answer (score 0):

You need to take a thread dump and analyze it carefully to understand where they are stuck, it is most likely thread safety issue in your code. We have faced similar locking issue in the past when we moved from Linux 4 machine to Linux 6 (much powerful machine with multiple CPU and cores). Faster machines can expose such long standing threading related programming bugs.