# Is visualvm able to detect livelocks?

Tags: java, visualvm, livelock

VisualVM is able to detect deadlocks: [Get deadlock detection from running programm or dump in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8126711/get-deadlock-detection-from-running-programm-or-dump-in-java)

Is VisualVM able to detect livelocks? If cannot do it automatically which actions possible to help to reveal livelocks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it cannot, because threads are doing something and it's impossible to detect if it's something useful or just moving back and forth