# Debug in Eclipse while running from command line ubuntu

Tags: eclipse, debugging, ubuntu, command-line

Is there a way I can debug my application (using breakpoints in eclipse) while running it from command line (ubuntu)? I'm using Eclipse Kepler version on Ubuntu 12.04LTS.

I know there's something like attach to process in .net, was wondering if eclipse has some such setup.

Thanks,

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are Java command line options to set to allow JVM to be remotely debugged?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/138511/what-are-java-command-line-options-to-set-to-allow-jvm-to-be-remotely-debugged)

Comment: Did you ever get to figure this out? I have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Is your application written in C or in Java?

If your application is in C and you are using CDT, you can attach to existing project by:

1. Run your application from terminal.
2. In Eclipse CDT, go to main menu "Run"->"Debug Configurations...", double-click "C/C++ Attach to Application" and press "Debug" (you should not need to specify executable and/or project).

For Java applications, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138511/what-are-java-command-line-options-to-set-to-allow-jvm-to-be-remotely-debugged)

Comment: My application is in Java. Thanks for your comment. I'll check out the link.

Comment: I'm lil' clueless on this. So, it would be like: i run my eclipse using  -agentlib:jdwp option and set break points and everything. then i run my shell script and it will hit those breakpoints. Please advise.

Comment: No. Your shell script is running java command - that's where you should add -agentlib and such. You run Eclipse as usual, but use the debug configuration UI to setup remote debugging session (even though the app is ran on the same system)

Comment: I added -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=1044 to my script, it runs fine but doesn't break at breakpoints. Please help