# Is there a way of debugging large OSGI bundle conglomerates in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, osgi

We are working on a large project consisting of many OSGI bundles, a few containing middleware features and a lot of bundles that contain certain plugings for this middleware. We use the org.eclipse.osgi JAR as our OSGI container. Currently building is done via ANT, the middleware is started via a batch file or shell script.

I was wondering and searching if there are ways to import big projects consisting of many ANT build files into Eclipse and run/debug this project in its entirety in Eclipse, so far I could not make out any way to do this for a big project.
All we can do at the moment is "printf debugging", which is kind of embarrassing ;)

Comment: You could start your VM (is there only one?) in debug mode and attach to it from Eclipse using something like -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=9090

Comment: +1 recreating a complex launch script in Eclipse is impractical. Remote debugging is the usual way to do this.

Comment: Ok, I'll have a look at that, there is only one VM, is there any "standard" tutorial that I should peruse?

Comment: You could have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/138511/what-are-java-command-line-options-to-set-to-allow-jvm-to-be-remotely-debugged and the pointed link: http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t53459.html

Comment: @AlexandreDupriez You should copy your comment into the Answer field below, so that LostBoy can accept it.

Comment: It works perfectly :) Had to go with -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=1044 though as indicated in the linked question, but thank you