# Divide by zero gives unicode #8734 character in Scala

Tags: scala, velocity

I'm using a velocity template in my Scala app which logs to a file.
 If I'm dividing by zero why do I get a unicode representation (`&#8734;`) in my templated log file and `Infinity` printed on Eclipse console when debugging the below code?

```
val params = MMap.empty[String, Any]
params.put("percent", ((23.6 * 100.0) / 0.0))
debug(params.get("percent")).toDouble + "")
```

Comment: I need to pinpoint where the conversion from `Infinity` to `&#8734;` happens?

Comment: I guess, `Double.toString`

Comment: According to GitHub, [nope](https://github.com/scala/scala/search?q=%E2%88%9E&ref=cmdform). @Vaibhav , what frameworks/logging are you using?

Comment: slf4j which uses a velocity template format log output. What I find confusing is why a simple string without special characters : `Infinity` gets converted to unicode?

Comment: @Vaibhav : made an edit to the answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Probably because this character is `U+221E INFINITY`, i.e. `∞`, i.e. **the infinity sign**?

---

As to **where** it comes from, well, it's **unlikely that it comes from Scala itself**. I've taken the liberty to d/l the current [master](https://github.com/scala/scala) and search for `221e`, `221E`, `∞`, `8734` and even `Infinity`. I've found nothing indicative of such a conversion.

---

There's a simple solution for finding what does the conversion (and this is general for such problems):

- run your app with debugger access (for externally started JVMs you need [debug mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138511/what-are-java-command-line-options-to-set-to-allow-jvm-to-be-remotely-debugged) with `suspend=y` preferably),
- put a breakpoint on that `debug` statement,
- step through until you find the offending code.