# How to create batch file and execute jar file with arguments

Tags: java, batch-file

How create a batch file to a jar file that contains a `SortFile.java` class that is responsible for sorting the content of a file. This class is taking 2 arguments the first one is `sort` and the second is `file name`. I would like to create a batch file that will be moved to `cmd` and after the `path` to this batch file user can pass those 2 `args`. The `.jar` let's say is on `C:\dir\SortFile.jar` and I would like to execute this batch from any location. Could someone help me, I never wrote a batch files that executes jars. I google it, but all examples I found did not explain it as well, there was no example for that case I need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's go step by step:

> The .jar let's say is on C:\dir\SortFile.jar

So your batch file probably should contain `java -jar C:\dir\SortFile.jar sort fileToSort` (assuming of course that you compiled that Java code already, and that you build the JAR file so that it can be called that way)

> I would like to execute this batch from any location.

Then that batch file should be located somewhere in your `%PATH%`.

If you prefer to use the CLASSPATH, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25176153/how-to-write-a-batch-file-to-set-classpath-and-execute-java-programs) for guidance.