# How do we build debug version of VM

Tags: java

I am getting the following error when i pass the graph level option

"Error: VM option 'PrintIdealGraphLevel' is develop and is available only in debug version of VM."

I am using openjdk 9.

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/138511/what-are-java-command-line-options-to-set-to-allow-jvm-to-be-remotely-debugged

Comment: Here is how to build the OpenJDK with option of FAST_DEBUG http://hg.openjdk.java.net/build-infra/jdk8/raw-file/tip/README-builds.html

Answer (score 2):

Here is how to Build OpenJDK 8, and the instructions should be the same for Java 9.

http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk11/raw-file/tip/doc/building.html

You want to enable the FAST_DEBUG option in the configuration.

Comment: "While this link may answer the question, ... ... " (just kidding ;-))

Comment: Top hit on google and the link is dead (not kidding) :-)

Comment: this file is also inside the downloaded (cloned) project, folder `doc`