# How to Debug java code from Batch file

Tags: eclipse, debugging, batch-file

I have a .bat file which is internally calling a java file. Something like

```
if "%type%"=="filter" %COMMAND% ExcelFilterLoader %filename% %cutdate% %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9
```

Now i want to debug the java class and see where control goes in java class (which is called using.bat file). Using eclipse when i put debuggers in the class the control doesnt stop there while in log i can see the process has completed. Hence, debuggers doesn't work in this scenario like in normal java application. Do i need to do something else to enable debugging when java class is called from .bat file?

Comment: You should take a look at "debug configuration". In this, you can configuration how to launch your soft (with a .bat for example ;) )

Comment: Modify the bat file so that is starts [Java with debugging enabled](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/138511/what-are-java-command-line-options-to-set-to-allow-jvm-to-be-remotely-debugged). Afterwards you can connect to the Java-VM using Eclipse or any other Java debugger.

Comment: Modified my question to be more descriptive