# Debug a jar that is being used by other application from eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, jar, remote-debugging

I have a Java application that must be launched from a shell script. This application uses a jar library that I want to modify and debug from eclipse. I have tried it and I failed.

## What I have tried

I have compile my library to generate the jar. In the folder where the application looks for the mentioned jar, I have renamed the original one and created a symbolik link to mine.

Then, from eclipse, I have done the following:

- Right click on my jar's `project > debug as > debug configurations`.
- Select `Remote java Application` and `Connection Type = Standard (Socket listen)`

At this point, I can see a label at the bottom right telling: `"Waiting to vm to connect"`.

Next I have gone to the  application's main folder and executed the launcher script.

I am sure that the application is using the modified library because I have added a `System.out.printlin("...")` and I can see it in the console. Despite of this, the debug mode is not activated in eclipse, and the application is not paused.

Note: I have compiled the proyect with make.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For remote debugging, the JVM that is being used to run the application must be c[onfigured to run in debug mode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/138511/639520). So you'll need to include those options in the script that's launching your application.

Having said that, what is so special about the shell script that it can't be converted into a run configuration to launch directly from Eclipse?

Comment: So what I need is to modify the script's java call to include debug flags, ok. Answering your question: It is a long script that performs some operations and give the application some inputs, that in several cases are files that are searched with relative paths.