# Debugging Java classes which are called from Windows batch files

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a java project A which is dependent on another project B. I want to debug the java class of project B while starting the batch files from project A. How can I achieve this in **Eclipse** ?

Comment: This is very vague.  Why can't you just start the batch files, and then select Debug As on Project B in Eclipse?

Answer (score 4):

You can attach tell java to allow connecting to debug by passing the command line parameters (legacy style):

```
-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8000
```

The newer style ([JVM TI interface used](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22631355/7421645)):

```
-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n
```

You should then be able to attach eclipse to debug:

> Configure Eclipse for remote debugging by specifying host and port.
>   host: localhost, port:8000

See this answer: [What are Java command line options to set to allow JVM to be remotely debugged?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/173447/7421645)