# How to debug a jar in eclipse when run with this command java -jar target/TextSecureServer-1.22.jar server config/development.yml

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, jar, remote-debugging

I am editing SecureServer Project in eclipse but I am executing it using below command in separate command line

```
java -jar target/TextSecureServer-1.22.jar server config/development.yml
```

How can I attach eclipse debugger to this running jar file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A running Java application which did not include the JVM flags to specify debug mode **cannot** be attached to a debugger. You will need to restart the application specifying the appropriate arguments. You will find [sufficient information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138511/what-are-java-command-line-options-to-set-to-allow-jvm-to-be-remotely-debugged) on these command line options

**For Java 5 and above**

```
-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8000
```

**For old versions**

```
-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=4000
```

**Note** : The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jpda/conninv.html) does say :

> A process to be debugged need not have been started in debug mode(ie,
>   with -agentlib:jdwp or -Xrunjdwp)

But this could be something thats not available yet. You can watch a running application using a tool like [processexplorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer.aspx) to see that there are no default listen ports when you run a java application without the arguments.