# Debug external launched jar file

Tags: java, debugging

I would like to debug an external launched jar application inside my Eclipse.

The way I'm launching the `jar` file is:

```
java -jar "D:\tools\swagger-codegen-cli.jar" generate -i http://guest1:8080/dbox/cmng/swagger.json -l typescript-angular2 -v
```

This `jar` file is generated using `mvn package` and copied in `D:\tools\`.

I've cloned git repository and I've imported the maven project inside Eclipse.

Is there any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run your jar with

```
java 
  -Xdebug 
  -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=8888
  -jar myjar.jar
```

In Eclipse you have to make a debug configuration. For a remote java appilcation. With 8888 as the port.

Comment: That would mean this question was a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138511/what-are-java-command-line-options-to-set-to-allow-jvm-to-be-remotely-debugged

Comment: you are right, except the hint to the eclipse launch configuration