# vagrant debug can't access debug port 8000 from host machine

Tags: java, tomcat, vagrant, remote-debugging, jdb

Connections to port 8000 from host machine do not work (connection refused), but local debugging works on the guest machine.

I'm running tomcat 8.5 inside a vagrant box with centos image and self signed cert. The host machine is running windows 7. I can access tomcat's manager application on a secure port 8443 with https, and I can access my webapp also on a secure port 8443 with https. 8443 is not forwarded. Non-secure connections also work on host port 8080, which is forwarded to guest port 80 on vagrant box.

After shutting down tomcat, `bin/shutdown.sh` and restarting in debug mode via `bin/catalina.sh jpda start` I can attach jdb on port 8000 via `jdb -attach 8000` and I can view threads and classes, and after setting a breakpoint and hitting the app on the secure 8443 I can step through the execution.

I have tried forwarding host port 9000 to guest port 8000 in the Vagrantfile, and also tried various connectors set in tomcat's bin/server.xml to allow connections on port 8000. To allow remote connections, I had to add context files in tomcat's conf/Catalina/localhost with the following text for tomcat's manager application as well as my application:

```
<Context privileged="true" antiResourceLocking="false"
         docBase="${catalina.home}/webapps/manager">
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve" allow="^.*$" />
  </Context>
```

I feel like there is probably something else I need to do for tomcat to allow a remote connection on port 8000, but I'm unable to find it with a couple hours of google searches and experimentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

In catalina.sh, the JPDA variables are set in an if statement. I was allowing these variables to define how to connect. JPDA_ADDRESS was set as `JPDA_ADDRESS="localhost:8000"` I removed "localhost:" so it is now set as `JPDA_ADDRRESS="8000"`. I can connect from STS on the host machine now. Below is the if statement from catalina.sh that I changed to allow connections outside the guest machine.

```
if [ "$1" = "jpda" ] ; then
  if [ -z "$JPDA_TRANSPORT" ]; then
    JPDA_TRANSPORT="dt_socket"
  fi
  if [ -z "$JPDA_ADDRESS" ]; then
    JPDA_ADDRESS="8000" // only this line changed. was set to "localhost:8000"
  fi
  if [ -z "$JPDA_SUSPEND" ]; then
    JPDA_SUSPEND="n"
  fi
  if [ -z "$JPDA_OPTS" ]; then
    JPDA_OPTS="-agentlib:jdwp=transport=$JPDA_TRANSPORT,address=$JPDA_ADDRESS,server=y,suspend=$JPDA_SUSPEND"
  fi
  CATALINA_OPTS="$JPDA_OPTS $CATALINA_OPTS"
  shift
fi
```

catalina.sh probably isn't the best place to change the JPDA_ADDRESS. Other posts suggest defining the JPDA variables in setenv.sh, or a custom script that calls catalina.sh with the appropriate commands to start in debug mode.

In addition to this answer, I found an answer to another question which helped me figure out what was wrong. Antony Shumskikh's answer to [What are Java command line options to set to allow JVM to be remotely debugged?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138511/what-are-java-command-line-options-to-set-to-allow-jvm-to-be-remotely-debugged) was helpful.