# Connecting Eclipse to Docker Container for Remote Debugging

Tags: java, eclipse, docker, port, remote-debugging

I'm trying to connect eclipse to a docker container I have running but I am having trouble.

My docker run command is as follows:

```
docker run --rm -it -p 8000:8000 -p=8668:8080 -p 8010:8009 -p 8443:8443 \
--name myContainer -h theContainer -e JVM_ROUTE=myContainer1 myContainer:qa
```

In eclipse, I'm connecting with `localhost` as the host, and `8000` as the port. I go to Run->Debug Configurations->Remote Java Application, and I've created a new debug configuration.

[image: my project debugging]

When I click apply, then debug, I get a pop up error message `Failed to connect to remote VM.`

[image: cant connect]

What else do I need to do to get remote debugging working properly?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138511/what-are-java-command-line-options-to-set-to-allow-jvm-to-be-remotely-debugged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was solved by replacing `localhost` with my actual IP address.

Comment: I'm on a Mac, so I don't use `docker-machine`.

Comment: what do you mean by I am not using `docker-machine` this issue is related to `docker-machine`, and you are posting a wrong answer! this is relevant!

Answer (score 4):

A java application running in a docker container can be remotely debugged by

1. Enabling [JDWP](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/introclientissues005.html) for the java process in the container, e.g.

   ```
   java -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=y [...]
   ```

   or using the JAVA_OPTS environment variable

   ```
   JAVA_OPTS="-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=y"
   ```

   Note that `suspend=y` will prevent the application from starting until a remote debugger is attached to the JVM. If `suspend=n` is used, the application will start as normal allowing a remote debugger to connect at a later time.
2. Connecting to the process, e.g. through your IDE, using the port specified in the `address=<port>` settings above, and importantly the ip address of the *docker host* which, unless you are running on linux, is probably not `localhost`. If you are using `docker-machine`, the docker host ip can be displayed using `docker-machine ip`, e.g.

   ```
   $ docker-machine ip
   192.168.99.100
   ```

Comment: I am on a Mac. I'll give this a try now.

Answer (score 2):

OS: **Ubuntu 18 / Windows 10**

Java: **OpenJdk 12**

Docker Container: **Sprint boot application**

To connect Remote Debug in Eclipse you can follow these steps:

1. Put these lines in your application Dockerfile

```
    # For Windows Machine comment EXPOSE 7074 and add it to docker-compose.yml
    EXPOSE 7074
    ENV DEBUG_INFO="-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=0.0.0.0:7074,server=y,suspend=n"
    ENTRYPOINT [ "sh", "-c", "java ${DEBUG_INFO} -Dspring.profiles.active=docker -jar /pharmacy-service.jar" ]
```

For Windows, add ports in docker-compose.yml

```
  bank-service:
    image: ....
    environment:
       ...
    ports:
      - 9097:9097
      - 7074:7074
```

2. For Linux only, bring your docker application up and search for network, in my case **ecs-core_default**

```
    $ docker network ls
    NETWORK ID          NAME                DRIVER              SCOPE
    e63bb0decc92        bridge              bridge              local
    94aefcdbb5f3        ecs-core_default    bridge              local
```

3. For Linux only, now check IP for your application using,

```
    $ docker network inspect ecs-core_default
    [
        {
            "Name": "ecs-core_default",
            .....
            "IPAM": {
                "Driver": "default",
                "Options": null,
                "Config": [
                    {
                        "Subnet": "172.18.0.0/16",
                        "Gateway": "172.18.0.1"
                    }
                ]
            },
            .....
            "Containers": {
                "29bebdc31d6bf2057ed31074407c780cc718396ca49f58e766e098fceaa41a41": {
                    "Name": "ecs-core_pharmacy-service_1",
                    "EndpointID": "fadc9b40bfed1d4b2104b96fb6930bda47928256092c268aa4cb67407c2c1661",
                    "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:12:00:06",
                    "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.6/16",
                    "IPv6Address": ""
                }
            }
            .....
        }
    ]
```

4. For Linux only, copy IP address from Containers "IPv4Address": "172.18.0.6/16" i.e. **172.18.0.6**
5. For Windows 10 only, to find IP goto Control Panel -> Network and Internet -> View Network Status and task -> Change adapter settings -> Look for vEthernet. Open Properties goto Networking tab, select TCP/IPv4 and then click Properties button and copy IP.
   [image: Windows Docker IPv4]
6. In Eclipse, Run -> Debug Configuration, use IP (screenshot shows IPv4 for Linux, for Windows it will be 172.26.48.1) and exposed port (i.e 7074).
   [image]

Enjoy!!