# Remote debugging: No connection to Wildfly 14 on OpenJDK 11 at port 8787

Tags: java, debugging, wildfly, remote-debugging, java-11

I'm trying to connect my debugger to Wildlfy running on Open JDK 11.

Despite Wildfly says:

> `Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8787`

My IDE (IntelliJ IDEA CE 2018.1) claims that it doesn't get any connection:

> `Unable to open debugger port (localhost:8787): java.io.IOException "handshake failed - connection prematurally closed"`.

I'm starting Wildfly via `standalone.sh --debug` resulting in the following `JAVA_OPTS`:

```
-server
-Xms64m
-Xmx512m
-XX:MetaspaceSize=96M
-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman
-Djava.awt.headless=true
-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8787,server=y,suspend=n
--add-exports=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-exports=jdk.unsupported/sun.misc=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-exports=jdk.unsupported/sun.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED
--add-modules=java.se
```

Did something change in Java 9/10/11? Remote debugging with the exact same setup works fine when using Oracle JDK 8.

Using telnet I can confirm, that port `8787` is indeed not reachable.

**Update** after reading @ehsavoie's comment: `netstat -ln` on the server running Wildfly shows:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State   
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8787          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

So apparently with OpenJDK 11 the debug port is now bound to localhost by default.

Comment: Few doubts in general - Does that work on any other port by the way? What is the content of `standalone.sh`? How about tracing any failure logs for this?

Comment: `standalone.sh` is the [unpatched file from Wildfly 14.0.1](https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly-core/blob/6.0.2.Final/core-feature-pack/src/main/resources/content/bin/standalone.sh). Like what other ports? Wildfly is reachable via 8080, 8443 and 9990. 8787 is clearly exposed as debug port in the aforementioned JAVA_OPTS.

Comment: and if you set suspend to yes (y) does the startup suspend ? Just checking that the debug option is taken into account by the JVM

Comment: @ehsavoie indeed Wildfly suspends after logging `Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8787`. However my IDE (IntelliJ Idea) still says `Unable to open debugger port (localhost:8787): java.io.IOException "handshake failed - connection prematurally closed"`

Comment: What does netstat -ln show ?

Comment: @ehsavoie that was the important hint. According to netstat the debug port was bound to `127.0.0.1:8787` instead of `0.0.0.0:8787`. Apparently this changed with one of the latest Java releases. I'd accept this as an answer if you want to write one. Starting Wildfly with `standalone.sh --debug 0.0.0.0:8787` solves it.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The cause lies in the default behaviour that changed with Java 9 according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48396996/4014509): Beginning with Java 9, the JVM only accepts local connections unless otherwise specified.

Therefore the solution is fairly easy:

While with Java 8 it is sufficient to start Wildfly with `--debug`, with Java 9 I needed to change this to `--debug *:8787`.

Answer (score 41):

For jdk 11,you should use

```
-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=*:8787,server=y,suspend=n
```

instead.

Comment: Seems like in java8 address could just be port and by java11 address means address and port for systems with multiple interface, I presume.  Thanks for this.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was using Java 8 in my machine, but the remote Wildfly instance was running on Java 11.

When I changed my Java version to 11, it worked.