# Java remote debugging connection refused

Tags: java

I get connection refused when remotely debugging a Java application that executes on a different server. The JVM is version 16, and the OS is Ubuntu 21.04. I chose 8999 as an unused port on the server. Not much help from Oracle documentation on runjdwp.

The command line options are ...

```
-Xdebug \
-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8999,server=y,suspend=y \
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remote debugging: No connection to Wildfly 14 on OpenJDK 11 at port 8787](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53198798/remote-debugging-no-connection-to-wildfly-14-on-openjdk-11-at-port-8787)

Comment: Yes, the answer to your linked question also answers my question. The answer specifies *:<port> where I used IPv4 0.0.0.0:<port>.

Answer (score 8):

The socket 8999 on the remote host defaults to 127.0.0.1:8999 which only accepts connections from running on the same host. In order to accept connections from any host, I found that the following worked OK.

```
-Xdebug \
-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=0.0.0.0:8999,server=y,suspend=y \
```

Comment: Note that 0.0.0.0 is ip v4 Only.