# How to disable JDWP interface on linux server?

Tags: java, linux, jdwp

I've seen this question on stackoverflow, but without a clear answer. How do you disable JDWP on linux server? We had a security team recommend to disable JDWP due to RCE.

Ref: https://ioactive.com/hacking-java-debug-wire-protocol-or-how/

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are Java command line options to set to allow JVM to be remotely debugged?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/138511/608639)

Answer (score 1):

JDWP is only enabled if you ask for it (`-agentlib:jdwp`), so:
To disable: ***Don't ask.***

To see what not to do:
[What are Java command line options to set to allow JVM to be remotely debugged?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/138511/5221149)