# Problem encountered while remote debugging java application as a service

Tags: java, debugging, windows-services, remote-debugging, procrun

I followed this SO post:

[What are Java command line options to set to allow JVM to be remotely debugged?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138511/what-are-java-command-line-options-to-set-to-allow-jvm-to-be-remotely-debugged)

and was able to remotely debug my Java app that runs as a windows service through [prunsrv / procrun](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/procrun.html).

When I run the service with option `suspend=n`, I am able to connect remote debugger through eclipse:

```
myservice.exe //US//myservice --JvmOptions "-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:8111,server=y,suspend=n"
```

but when I give option `suspend=y`, I get the following error:

> Commons Daemon procrun failed with exit value: 5 (Failed to start
>   service)

any idea why `suspend=y` is resulting in this error. (Unfortunately detailed logs for prunsrv are not generated)

Comment: I suspect that your service check that JVM is alive and if you use `suspend=y` this check fails.

Comment: but when I check task manager, `myservice.exe (procrun)` is running.

Comment: @talex you were right. The way I validated this was, if I start my remote debugger within 2-3 secs of giving the start command to service, I did not see above error. This 2-3 seconds might be the validation time for checking for JVM alive.