# What is the most efficient/automated way to remote debug a Kafka/web application on a Linux VM from Windows desktop through IntelliJ IDEA/Eclipse?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, remote-debugging

I want to build, transfer, and remote debug a Kafka application on a Linux VM from Windows desktop using IntelliJ Idea and/or Eclipse. What is the most efficient/automated way to do this so that it relieves me from manually transferring (sftp) the application, set up for remote debugging etc?

I don't want to exit my IDE, but would like to debug the application on remote machine by modifying the app repeatedly. I would like to see the results in the IDE console window/web browser as applicable.

Comment: It's not clear how you're starting the application on the remote server, but regardless of it being a Kafka application, the instructions are the same for all Java apps. You must expose the JDWP port https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138511/what-are-java-command-line-options-to-set-to-allow-jvm-to-be-remotely-debugged An "automated way" might involve Ansible copying the files, then using systemctl to run your application