# Debugging with exec-maven-plugin

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea, exec-maven-plugin

I am using `exec-maven-plugin` to execute my java app and run debug from my IDE (IntelliJ) with the following setup:

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
   <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>1.4.0</version>
   <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>exec_1</id>
        <phase>deploy</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>java</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
   </executions>
   <configuration>
       <mainClass>com.myapp.app</mainClass>
   </configuration>
</plugin>
```

And it works very well. Then, I change my setup to execute a realistic `java` command line which would run the same app:

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
   <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.0</version>
   <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>exec_1</id>
        <phase>deploy</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>exec</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
   </executions>
   <configuration>
      <executable>java</executable>
       <arguments>
           <argument>-cp</argument>
           <argument>
               "dir1";"dir2;etc..."
           </argument>
           <argument>com.myapp.app</argument>
       </arguments>
   </configuration>
</plugin>
```

And it works to execute the application, but it does not attach the Debugger to the IDE. So, what additional argument I could add to make it catch the debug interruptions?

Comment: Why not just create a Run Configuration in IDEA and run it without Maven at all?

Comment: or run the build up to the phase you need and continue from the command line. Use the dependency:buildclasspath goal to get your classpath

Answer (score 0):

When you launch maven goal in debug mode - you are launching debug for the Maven goal process, but you need to debug the forked by the Maven goal JVM process. For this you can either

- specify the remote debug JVM options for this process like `-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=*:8000` (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/138511/2000323) SO post) and then launch [Remote Debug Configuration](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration-remote-debug.html) in IDE. See [this tutorial](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/tutorial-remote-debug.html#5918737a) about remote debug in IDE.
- use IDE's own [Run/Debug Configuration](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration-application.html) for launching and debugging the application.