# Can we debug deployed azure function from intellij?

Tags: java, azure, debugging, intellij-idea, azure-functions

I have developed a Java azure function and deployed it through IntelliJ(with Azure toolkit plugin support). I can do local run/debug on the function app from ide, as it nicely supports local run/debug.

Now the question is, Is there any way to debug code(or jar) that is deployed on Azure function(not sure if this has to be called remote debugging)? I searched through internet, was only seeing options to debug the app that is under development in ide(i.e., local code), but not able to find a way for deployed version. Is it possible to do this? or am I over-expecting from ides?

Comment: You are right, it is needed to use remote debugging. Start the deployed app in [debug mode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/138518/8203759) and attach your IDE to it via "Remote Application" run configuration

Comment: Referred link for debug mode; but couldn't find how I can control that in Azure portal. Can you please throw some light on how I can enable this for Azure functions?

Comment: In [function properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-maven-intellij#manage-function-apps-from-idea) insert java options from run configuration as shown [here](https://i.imgur.com/qSHkfze.png). Syntax is like [that](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-java-worker/issues/171#issuecomment-488521080)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, it is **not possible to Remote Debug** the function app with **Intellij IDE**.

**Here is the workaround I tried to do Remote Debugging of azure Function using Intellij IDE.**

After Deploying your function app into azure we can debug using **(REMOTE DEBUG)** while enabling it into the Azure portal. That is possible only in **Visual Studio** only.

[image]

After ***enabling*** **Remote Debug** in the Azure portal. The port of related visual studio can enable after enabling this Remote Debugging feature. I tried to add the Visual Studio debugging port like (`VS19 - 4024`) [remote debugger port assignments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugger-port-assignments?view=vs-2022) & other visual studio port.

I end up unable to open the port.

[image]

**Note:**

> In Azure except for the 8080/443 port, other ports are blocked in Azure.

Comment: Thank you for the information. However, I couldn't try this approach yet. I will give it a try and update here