# Error running 'application': Unable to open debugger port (localhost:8000): java.io.IOException "handshake failed - connection prematurally closed

Tags: java, docker, maven

The host is set to `localhost` and the port is set to `8000`.

Command line arguments:
`-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8000`

Trying to debug my application. Tried setting the port to 5000 and 8983 and got the `'connection refused' error. command line arguments is not editable`.  Here is the screenshot

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Comment: Looks similar too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138511/what-are-java-command-line-options-to-set-to-allow-jvm-to-be-remotely-debugged, please consider using `address=*:8000` instead, and please check that port 8000 is not already being used by another service

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.