# Debugging while working on a build through the terminal

Tags: debugging, terminal, podman

I am not used to working on makefiles or coding through the terminal.

I recently took a class which had us create a build through a makefile on a podman container that we would "make" and run through a terminal window.

We were told to debug through the terminal, usually by reacting to the error codes.
This was in Java and for some reason System.out.println didn't work so I ended up using System.err.println just to read out what my code and data structures contained.

I really struggled to debug my code this way,'blind.' I could print out all of the key data structures and areas of my code that I wanted to check. But the ouput would end up overwhelming me, and if I wanted to only check specific areas of my code I would have to write one or two print statement(s), then run the program to check, then delete, write a different one, run the program, delete... and that took so much time it was unbearable.

I was used to working in an IDE and I missed being able to set up breakpoints and to simply 'walk' through my code a step at a time.

Does anyone know how to use the features of an IDE in this kind of a setup?

Is debugging code 'blind' this way typical when you are working on a real project?

Does anyone have any general debugging tips when you are in this kind of a situation?
Something tells me I just wasn't working 'smart' especially because the code itself really wasn't too complicated I could create a very straightforward block diagram for it.

Thank you.
Tom Banker

Answer (score 0):

You can attach an IDE's debugger to a java process running within a podman container. The java process just needs to be started with an additional argument like `-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=*:5005`, which is needed for [debugging](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jdb.html), and then the debugger can be attached to port `5005`. Refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138511/what-are-java-command-line-options-to-set-to-allow-jvm-to-be-remotely-debugged) for more details. Your Containerfile/Dockerfile and `Makefile` would need to look something like the below:

**Containerfile:**

```
FROM docker.io/eclipse-temurin:17.0.7_7-jre-alpine

COPY build/libs/spring-boot-demo*.jar demo.jar

CMD ["java", "-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=*:5005", "-jar", "demo.jar"]
```

**Makefile:**

```
run:
    podman build -t spring-boot-demo:latest .
    podman run --rm \
        -p 8080:8080 \
        -p 5005:5005 \
        spring-boot-demo:latest
```